# How can I send an image in base64 with ng2-file-upload?

Tags: angular, base64, ng2-file-upload

The title is my question, how I can send an image in base64 with `ng2-file-upload`?

My code in **Angular 4**:

```
public uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({
   url: URL,
   allowedMimeType: ['application/pdf', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png'],
   maxFileSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024, // 10 MB
   queueLimit: 3,
   disableMultipart: true,
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this way:

```
saveImages() {
    let fileCount: number = this.uploader.queue.length;
    if (fileCount > 0) {
    this.uploader.queue.forEach((val, i, array) => {
        let fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onloadend = (e) => {
            let imageData = fileReader.result;
            let rawData = imageData.split("base64,");
            if (rawData.length > 1) {
                rawData = rawData[1];
            }
        }
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(val._file);
    });
}
```

took from here:
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/issues/949

Comment: I will testing this, tnks.